# color for section headers in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sections

I am creating a table where I want all sections' headers coloured black and sections' footers- green.
Headers/footers are created using the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` class

```
let sectionFooterView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = {
        UITableViewHeaderFooterView()
    }()
```

Code for setting the background colours:

```
func tableView(_: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection _: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = mainView.sectionHeaderView
    view.tintColor = .black
    return view
}

func tableView(_: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection _: Int) -> CGFloat {
    UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(_: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection _: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = mainView.sectionFooterView
    view.tintColor = .green
    return view
}

func tableView(_: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection _: Int) -> CGFloat {
    UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

I get coloured only header/footer somewhere in the middle of the table, but most headers/footers are still clear color. What is there to change?

Comment: Why/what is `mainView`, you can see multiple footer/header view at the same time, but you are using only one?

Comment: mainView is from a View file where I create sectionFooterView (the first part of code mentioned). I want the same one to be used in every section.

Comment: Just to try: replace `let view = mainView.sectionFooterView` with `let view = UITableViewHeaderFooterView()` will it work?

Comment: it did work! Thank you

Comment: It's as I said. You are using the same `headerView` but a view can't be at two place at the sample place, so if you would see 2 headerView on screen, there is an issue. Same logic for `footerView`.